# How would I go about this problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Determine the potential for the field:

$F=<10xy+3y^{2}+2y,5x^{2}+6xy+2x+3>$

Now calculate the integral of $\int F\cdot dr$

where C is the path of the parabola $y=x^{2}−6x+8$ from the point $(0,8)$ to the point $(3,−1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Hint:

1. put $x=t$, find $y$ and hence $dx,dy$
2. Find $F$ as function of $t$
3. Evaluate $F\cdot dr$
4. Integrate from 0 to 3